# Shielded Stride while Mounted

Tags: fighter, pathfinder-2e, mounted-combat

### Pathfinder 2E

I'm building a Human Fighter into a sort of Knight character. I was curious about the 4th-level Class Feat **Shielded Stride.** The feat reads

> When your shield is up, your enemies' blows can't touch you. When you have your shield
> raised, you can Stride to move half your Speed without triggering reactions that are
> triggered by your movement (such as Attacks of Opportunity). You can use Shielded Stride
> while Flying or Swimming instead of Striding if you have the corresponding movement type.

This feat is a feature and not a feat that requires an action in order to use it. So my question is, if I

- **Mount** a horse (1 action)
- **Raise Shield** (2nd action),
- **Command Animal** (3rd action, my part)

  - **Move/Stride** (3rd action, horses part) (only moving half of it's speed as the feat requires)

Would the horse's movement trigger any reactions, such as **Attacks of Opportunity** or would it not because I have taken the **Shielded Stride** feat?

A similar, but opposing question: can a horse's movement be used within Combat Feats like **Sudden Charge**? I would hope so, but if my understanding is correct the horse's movement has the prerequisite of me using **Command Animal** to make it move, while **Sudden Charge's** movement is included within it's 2 actions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Your horse cannot use and does not benefit from Shielded Stride or other Actions/Activities you have

Your horse is its own creature that does not have Shielded Stride; therefor when it Strides, even Commanded by you, it will trigger Reactions keyed to movement. There are no 'transitive property' of Feats relating to [Mounted Combat](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=463).

Similarly, Sudden Charge is completely disallowed by the rules of [Mounted Defense](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=465).

---

Currently, using a mount in combat is pretty restrictive and difficult. Hopefully your GM will work with you to decide what does or does not work. I would personally rule that Shielded Stride affects your mount's Strides (given that you follow the half speed rule) but that may vary by table. The [Cavalier archetype](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=53) will also help greatly if you intend to ride into combat frequently.

Comment: This is a wonderful answer! Thank You! I actually plan to take the Cavalier archetype at level 2. I'd love to see some new feats in the future that will allow more flexibility for mounted combat. Perhaps like `Nimble Mount` which would allow you to to use a single move action without triggering reactions. Perhaps my GM would allow some custom feats.

Comment: Never hurts to ask